# jQuery adding style="overflow: hidden;"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a bit of code to hide my menu, the menu is not complete but I am trying to use `jQuery.slideUp()` function but it adds `style="overflow: hidden;"` to the code so when I use .show one of my elements is hidden which is `#nav:after` and `#nav:before` which adds a small arrow to the bottom of the menu

here is the js code

```
  $("span#start_button").click(function () {
        if ($("#nav").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#nav").show("fast");
        } else {
            $("#nav").slideUp();
        }
    });
```

and here is the result on [this site](http://laggy.koding.com/)

How can I stop `.slideUp()` from creating `style="overflow: hidden;"` ?

Comment: What do you want to do instead?  If you want it to just slide up without disappearing you could use `animate()` instead.

Comment: look on the site, I dont want the arrow to disappear after using the `.slideUp()` function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must remove the `overflow:hidden` on the callback of the `slideUp()` function
so you can try

```
$("#nav").slideUp('fast', function(){ $('#nav').css('overflow','visible') });
```

Or you can force it by css

```
#nav{overflow:visible!important}
```

Comment: And, *why* should we?
Because (from Andrey's answer), this is a bug in older jQuery. Personally, I found upgrading my jQuery version more convenient.

Answer (score 7):

This is [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12630) in older jquery.
This code replace standart function "slideDown" and delete overflow property.

```
!(function (jQuery, origSlideDown) {
jQuery.fn.slideDown = function (speed, easing, callback) {
    var self = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var origCallback;

    for (var i = 0, len = args.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (jQuery.isFunction(args[i])) {
            origCallback = args[i];
            args[i] = function () {
                origCallback.call(this);
                self.css('overflow', '');
            }
        }
    }

    if (!origCallback) {
        args.push(function () {
            self.css('overflow', '');
        });
    }

    return origSlideDown.apply(this, args);
};
})(jQuery, jQuery.fn.slideDown);
```

Comment: jQuery.support.shrinkWrapBlocks seems to be set inadvertently when box-sizing is changed in resets and frameworks like Bootstrap, but this is fixed in jQuery 1.11.

Answer (score 1):

Override that style -

```
   $("#nav").slideUp();
   $("#nav").css({'overflow':'visible'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the default styling by modifying the style attribute of html.

```
else {
       $("#nav").slideUp();
       $("#nav").attr("style","overflow:visible");
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are almost as bad as link only answers. They're not really answers at all. A good answer contains explanations and reasoning and possibly some sources or authority.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
else {
   $("#nav").slideUp();
   $("#nav").css("overflow","visible");
}
```